# How to use both state and query params with useNavigate in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

React Router 6.3.0

Is there a way to be able to pass state and query params in same navigate call, and have both applied?

Steps to Reproduce

1. Try

   ```
   navigate(
     { 
       pathname: "/search",
       search: `?${createSearchParams({ query: someQuery })}`,
       state: { someAttributeName: someAttributeValue }
     }
   );
   ```

Note that the query params are passed in the URL but state will be null.

2. Try

   ```
   navigate(
     "/search",
     {
       search: `?${createSearchParams({query: someQuery})}`,
       state: { someAttributeName: someAttributeValue }
     }
   );
   ```

Note that the state is passed but the query params are not applied.

Answer (score 2):

The search value can be sent in the `To` object in the first argument, and the state as a property in the `options` object in the second argument.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/hooks/use-navigate)

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: {
>       replace?: boolean;
>       state?: any;
>       relative?: RelativeRoutingType;
>     }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

[`To` type](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/packages/history/index.ts#L178)

> ```
> export type To = string | Partial<Path>;
> ```

[`Partial<Path>` type](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/packages/history/index.ts#L68-L92)

> ```
> /**
>  * The pathname, search, and hash values of a URL.
>  */
> export interface Path {
>   /**
>    * A URL pathname, beginning with a /.
>    *
>    * @see https://github.com/remix-run/history/tree/main/docs/api-reference.md#location.pathname
>    */
>   pathname: Pathname;
>
>   /**
>    * A URL search string, beginning with a ?.
>    *
>    * @see https://github.com/remix-run/history/tree/main/docs/api-reference.md#location.search
>    */
>   search: Search;
>
>   /**
>    * A URL fragment identifier, beginning with a #.
>    *
>    * @see https://github.com/remix-run/history/tree/main/docs/api-reference.md#location.hash
>    */
>   hash: Hash;
> }
> ```

Your code:

```
navigate(
  { 
    pathname: "/search",
    search: `?${createSearchParams({ query: someQuery })}`,
  },
  { state: { someAttributeName: someAttributeValue } },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to append `?`.

```
navigate(
  {
    pathname: "/search",
    search: createSearchParams({ query: "someQuery" }).toString(),
  },
  { state: { someAttributeName: "someAttributeValue" } },
);
```